# how to evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1 - xy) \cdot \text{Li}_{4}(1 - x)}{x(1 - x)(1 - xy)} \,dy\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, closed-form

> **how to evaluate** $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1 - xy) \cdot \text{Li}_{4}(1 - x)}{x(1 - x)(1 - xy)} \,dy\,dx$$

### My attempt

$$ \Omega =\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1 - xy) \cdot \text{Li}_{4}(1 - x)}{x(1 - x)(1 - xy)} \,dy\,dx$$

$$
* \Omega = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{Li}_{4}(1 - x)}{x(1 - x)} \,dx \cdot \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1 - xy)}{1 - xy} \,dy
$$

$$
= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{Li}_{4}(1 - x)}{x(1 - x)} \,dx \cdot \left[-\frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1 - xy)}{1 - xy} \,d(1 - xy)\right]
$$

$$
= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{Li}_{4}(1 - x)}{x(1 - x)} \,dx \cdot \left[-\frac{1}{2x} \ln^2(1-xy)\bigg|_{0}^{1}\right]
$$

$$= - \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^2(1 - x) \cdot \text{Li}_{4}(1 - x)}{x^2(1 - x)} \,dx$$

Comment: Why do you think the integral has a closed form?

Comment: [tag:euler-sums] may be relevant here